# error connecting mysql 8 with django

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I am using python 3.6, mysql-community-server-8.0.11-1 and using fedora 28
I am trying to setup mysql for my django application
But I am receiving Segmentation fault

```
(myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost myblog]$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I use the default sqlite3 database, server comes up.

Also when I run `django-admin dbshell` I get the following error:

```
(myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost myblog]$ django-admin dbshell
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/run/media/saurabhkumar/9bba3767-3aa7-4b39-a4a7- 
 331f939ae4d9/django_projects/common_lounge/myblog/myblogvenv/bin/django- 
    admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/run/media/saurabhkumar/9bba3767-3aa7-4b39-a4a7-331f939ae4d9/django_projects/common_lounge/myblog/myblogvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/run/media/saurabhkumar/9bba3767-3aa7-4b39-a4a7-331f939ae4d9/django_projects/common_lounge/myblog/myblogvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/run/media/saurabhkumar/9bba3767-3aa7-4b39-a4a7-331f939ae4d9/django_projects/common_lounge/myblog/myblogvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/run/media/saurabhkumar/9bba3767-3aa7-4b39-a4a7-331f939ae4d9/django_projects/common_lounge/myblog/myblogvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/run/media/saurabhkumar/9bba3767-3aa7-4b39-a4a7-331f939ae4d9/django_projects/common_lounge/myblog/myblogvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/saurabhkumar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite'
```

This is my project structure:

```
(myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost myblog]$ ls
db.sqlite3  manage.py  myblogvenv  mysite
(myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost myblog]$ cd mysite
(myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost mysite]$ ls
__init__.py  __pycache__  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py
```

Database section in settings.py looks like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blog',
        'USER': 'bloguser',
        'PASSWORD': 'Blog#user1',
        'HOST': '/var/lib/mysql',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Using the following packages

```
(myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost mysite]$ pip list
Package     Version
----------- -------
Django      2.0.6  
mysqlclient 1.3.12 
pip         10.0.1 
pytz        2018.4 
setuptools  39.2.0 
wheel       0.31.1
```

Any pointer on how to debug/fix the issue will help me proceed.

Comment: can you post settings py. It is something related to django mysite model no db connections.

Comment: settings.py can be accessed from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1y7pGQjmNXfLiYw46oOiC_0DADfY8JU7V

Comment: include this in the install_apps  'django.contrib.sites',

Comment: Added django.contrib.sites' in the install_apps section, still no luck...

Comment: have you run the migrate command?

Comment: Yes, I ran it resulted in segmentation fault                                         
 (myblogvenv) [saurabhkumar@localhost myblog]$ python manage.py migrate
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @saurabh742 shouldn't the `HOST` part of the `DATABASES` settings point to an IP address instead of a file?

Comment: @Ralf sure... I have tried both 127.0.0.1 and localhost as HOST, but still same error.