# Django Segmentation fault when changing database to mysql in settings.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

My question is similar to the one at [error connecting mysql to django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983902/error-connecting-mysql-8-with-django) which has gone unanswered.

I am using **python 3.6.5**, **mysql server-5.7.29** and **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. I am trying to setup mysql for my django application but I am receiving Segmentation fault.

```
(env) monu@monu:~/Desktop/ShubhamProject/ShubhamProject$ python manage.py runserver
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I use the default sqlite3 database, server comes up.

Database section in settings.py looks like

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'sports_website',
        'USER': 'nonroot',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Using the following packages

```
asgiref==3.2.3
Django==3.0.3
django-crispy-forms==1.8.1
mysqlclient==1.4.6
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Comment: This is probably due to a wrong/incompatible version of openssl. I'd reinstall the build libraries for your system, as documented [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python): `sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential libssl-dev` and then reinstall mysqlclient.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. I run update and upgrade before and after installing mysqlclient and verified that the packages are up to date by running your suggested packages list as well.

Comment: try opening a python shell in your virtualenv, import `MySQLdb` and connect manually to your db (see [here](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#some-examples)). This will at least tell us whether this is related to Django or just to mysqlclient.

Comment: The segmentation fault occurs when I try importing MySQLdb

Answer (score 2):

install pymysql and add below in settings.py on top.

```
import pymysql
pymysql.version_info = (1, 4, 6, 'final', 0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Comment: pymysql solution does work. Thanks a lot. However I don't understand why mysqlclient does not seem to be working when it the recommended way by django docs.

Answer (score 0):

this is because django use MySQLdb drive，but MYSQLdb not support python3, so set the drive is pymysql in settings.py:
first :pip install pymysql
and add: import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

Comment: welcome to stack-overflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/tour for give best feedback here. wish you for the best